# Doing lots of business work in development, but developer title. Should I ask for it to be changed?

Tags: interviewing, resume, software-industry, career-development

I'm titled as a developer however since starting in my current position I've accumulated more and more work that I would consider business analysis oriented.

I write specifications, create workflow diagrams, cost-benefit analysis and in many ways find myself doing more business analyst work than developer work.

I'm completely ok with this and I don't want it to change at all but I'm concerned that if I were to move onto another position in the future that simply being titled as a "Developer" is going to have to be constantly explained to future employers. I'm worried most hiring officers would just look at the job title when skimming resumes, and not an explanation of the duties I performed.

Should I ask for my job title to be amended to something like "Business Systems Analyst" or is this a completely normal situation that I'm over thinking?

Comment: What are your long term ambitions? Are you intending on staying in development or being a business analyst in the future?

Comment: Yes, if that's your ambition, ask for a title change. This can also be useful internally (assuming you want to keep moving in that direction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be more business orientated in the future. If that is indeed the case then it's going to be important to have your job title updated to reflect your intended future position. If you're intending on staying a developer in future this likely doesn't matter as much as that is the job title they would be seeking (and your skills in these areas are GREAT points under your job title).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have your title updated to "**Analyst Developer**".

This makes it obvious to other IT industry people that you are capable of performing the business analysis side of things as well as having a background (or deep skills even) in development.

Answer (score 0):

Many employees have titles that do not reflect what they do. It's very strange but seems to be the norm, especially in larger companies. I have come to find the titles **are really for HR and business matrix purposes**.

Next, you assume a 1 to 1 correlation with your internal title to what you type on your resume.

On **your** resume, you can expand, shrink or morph the position title appropriately, to show case what it is you actually do. I think you would actually confuse them if it showed developer and then the description was business. Why even go there...?

Now if you want, like others pointed out, you can try to use it to your advantage as well. However, you have to explain why you are business capable **and** a developer. It could be more valuable than just either/or.

Next, are you the only one with that title doing that work? May want to ponder how that happened? Did they think you were better suited for that or this...or just where the work was at the time?

At the end of the day, the one or two word title you put above the actual work description (in paragraphs or multiple bullets) on your resume, is probably close to irrelevant.